# Neon animation is deprecated in polymer 2.0 so Does that mean we should stop using neon-animated-pages?

Tags: polymer-2.x, neon-animation

Under the changes in Polymer 2.0 section of the README, it states this element is now deprecated.[Neon Animation Update](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-07-12-an-update-on-neon-animation)

- Does that mean we should stop using neon-animated-pages?
- If web animation api is replacement then how use "**shared
  Transition**" in it.

Neon animation divided into 2 part

- animation effect (deprecated)
- animation behaviour (deprecated..?)

**Is Neon-animation-behaviour is also deprecated..?**

Answer (score 0):

About two month ago Polymer released an [article](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-07-12-an-update-on-neon-animation.html) regarding the neon animation.
To sum it up:

- They are not planning on maintaining the package anymore.
- If you are using Polymer elements that are depending on neon-animation they will replace them for you.
- If you're using neon-animation directly, you should start planning to eventually move off it.

For new projects the recommended approach would be to use

- CSS Keyframe Animations
- Web Animations API
- CSS Transitions

I in person would go with css transitions to achieve a page-transition but thats definitely just one way to do it.
You can find how to use CSS transitions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).
Some nice examples of page transitions can be found [here](http://freefrontend.com/css-page-transitions/).

Comment: My main aim is to use "NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior" and "NeonSharedElementAnimationBehavior", but as Neon-animation is deprecated how we can achive this Behaviors along with "Web Animation API".  _I want to achive effect likeAndroid Material Animation: Shared Element Transition_

Comment: I added a link in the end of my answer

Comment: thanks @Niklas .... Above link are seems to be helpful....! i will try this to develope with Web animation API.